# laravel 9 didn't make logout in the home blade page

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, authentication

I just started a new project in laravel 9
and trying to learn
the code generated by default from laravel in home.blade.page dosen't contain a logout option / no logout controller in http/controllers auth folder
even though I followed the tutorial step by step
what can I do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

by default Laravel project doesn't have login,logout and register functionality .
but it has starter kits for that
please refer to this link

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze